# Delphi ServerSocket Response to Client

Tags: http, delphi

I am new with using Delphi's ServerSocket component, and I need to send a response back to the client (The client is making the request using the HTTP Get method).

I cannot use DataSnap since I only have the Delphi Professional license.  I would like to use the TSocket components set.

Comment: There is also Indy which is in active development, and which includes a TIdHTTPServer component (so you don't need to implement the HTTP protocol yourself) and TIdTCPServer (in case you want to have total control)

Comment: There are a few problems with your post: 

1) It doesn't ask anything (a statement like *I want to ...* is not a question). 2) It lacks a problem description, ie what *exactly* you need help with. 3) It doesn't say what you have done sofar to solve your problem. Please [edit] your question to correct those issues.

Comment: FWIW, those components are extremely outdated, and later versions of Delphi don't even install them by default anymore. And as others have said, there's no need to reinvent the wheel. HTTP has already been encapsulated for you.